# Read DateTime from output of Stored Procedure into a Java Object

Tags: java, datetime, jpa, stored-procedures

I have a simple Stored Procedure -

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetErrorandTimestampDetails]
@IncidentID INT,
@Errorcount INT OUTPUT,
@timestamp DATETIME OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @Errorcount=COUNT(1) 
    FROM IncErrorInfo
    WHERE IncidentID=@IncidentID

    SELECT @timestamp=[Date Added]
    FROM Incident_Info
    WHERE ID=@IncidentID    
END
```

To access that from JPA code, I have written -

```
import java.sql.Date;
.
.
.
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("dbo.GetErrorandTimestampDetails")
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("IncidentID", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("Errorcount", Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("timestamp", Date.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
            .setParameter("IncidentID", incidentID);

    boolean status = storedProcedure.execute();

    HashMap returnVal = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    returnVal.put("ErrorCount",(Integer)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("Errorcount"));
    returnVal.put("TimeStamp", (Date)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("timestamp"));
    return returnVal;
```

The Date object only contains the date without any information of time. How do i get the time information as well? Is there a DateTime object to store it?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type you are looking for is [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! saved me so much code rewrite